# MailDefinition Outside of ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#

I'm looking to write a C# console app that will, in the process of running send out emails. I have the emails going out simply by doing something like:

```
     MailMessage message = new MailMessage("foo@foo.com", "bar@bar.com", "Test message", "Test message content");
     message.IsBodyHtml = true;
     message.Body = "<a href=\"http://www.daringfireball.net\">DaringFireball.net</a>";
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost"); // Your host here

     try
     {
        client.Send(message);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error trying to send the message: " + e.ToString());
     }
```

I was trying to find a way to do this with MailDefinition because these emails might be longer, but in the process of doing that I ran into a little problem. The CreateMailMessage method requires a System.Web.UI.Control which I don't have because I'm not an ASP.Net Application.

Has anyone run into this problem? Or found a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What does `MailDefinition` bring to the party that `MailMessage` can't do?

Comment: @JimMischel - `MailDefinition`'s `CreateMailMessage` method provides a neat way of creating a email message from a text file. `MailMessage` doesn't have anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you've used correct .Net Framework 4 and not .Net Framework 4 client as the target framework.
Add System.Web to the references of your project.

Then create the Mailmessage as:
MailMessage msgHtml = message.CreateMailMessage(recipients, replacements, new System.Web.UI.Control());

Comment: This solution appears to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185105/wcf-service-fails-to-send-mail-through-maildefinition

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `MailDefinition` being superior in any way. From MSDN:

> "Use the MailDefinition class to
>   simplify creating predefined e-mail
>   messages to be sent by a control. If
>   you want to send e-mail not using a
>   control, see the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=VS.80).aspx)
>   class." ([source
>   here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition(v=VS.80).aspx))

But suppose you have good reasons to prefer `MailDefinition` to regular `MailMessage` **then add reference of System.Web.dll to you project**. You don't have to run in IIS to use the classes in that assembly.