# WCF Service fails to send mail through MailDefinition

Tags: c#, wcf, email

```
    // stuff......

    return SendCreationMail(Membership.GetUser((Guid)request.UserEntityId), request, new Control());
}

private const string TemplateRoot = "~/app_shared/templates/mail/";
private const string ServerRoot = TemplateRoot + "server/";

public static bool SendCreationMail(MembershipUser user, IServerAccountRequest request, Control owner)
{
    var definition = new MailDefinition { BodyFileName = string.Concat(ServerRoot, "creation.htm"), IsBodyHtml = true };
    var subject = "New {0} account created!".FormatWith(request.ServerApplicationContract.Id);

    var data = ExtendedData(DefaultData, subject, user);

    data.Add("<%ServerApplication%>", request.ServerApplicationContract.Id);
    data.Add("<%ServerApplicationName%>", request.ServerApplicationContract.ApplicationName);
    data.Add("<%AccountUsername%>", request.AccountUsername);

    data.Add("<%ServerInfo%>", "/server/{0}/info".FormatWith(request.ServerApplicationContract.Id.ToLower()));

    return definition.CreateMailMessage(user.Email, data, owner).Send(subject, ApplicationConfiguration.MailSenderDisplayName);
}
```

I get:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: basepath
>
> at System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Combine(String appPath, String basepath,
>   String relative)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(String
>   recipients, IDictionary replacements, Control owner)
>   at
>   Damnation.Website.Main.Common.MailTemplating.Server.SendCreationMail(MembershipUser
>   user, IServerAccountRequest request, Control owner)
>   at Damnation.Website.Main.Common.MailTemplating.Server.SendCreationMail(IServerAccountRequest
>   request)
>   at Damnation.Website.Main.Business.Model.ServerAccountRequest.UpdateRequestsAfterServerProcessing(IEnumerable`1
>   results)

Thing is I don't have an actual Control to pass to it, I'd like to know how to setup a control that avoids this senseless exception. I'm using a relative path... so this makes no sense.

The application that has the service is under ASP.NET WebForms .NET 4. The consumer application is a console application also under .NET 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I learned that this is happening because it cannot find the path of the control when trying to execute your definition.CreateMailMessage. You want to create a blank web user control. Maybe this is not the most elegant solution but it does the work.

This is what I did:

1) Add a Web User Control file in your project, for example Test.ascx.

2) In your .svc file add the following code:

```
Page page = new Page();

Test test = (Test)page.LoadControl("Test.ascx");
```

3) Update your definition.CreateMailMessage line to:

```
return definition.CreateMailMessage(user.Email, data, test).Send(subject, ApplicationConfiguration.MailSenderDisplayName);
```

You will no longer get the basepath null exception.

Comment: I'm getting an exception on the `LoadControl` call: "relative virtual path is not allowed here". This is a console application in .Net 4.5.2 on VS 2015 Community.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was because I was on a project .NET console application, when I passed the code to ASP.NET not I run well without creating Page and Test.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but the problem for me was that I was using relative paths for my BodyFileName and EmbeddedObjects. Changing them to absolute paths fixed this error for me.